# Can I prefetch specific data to a specific cache level in a CUDA kernel?

Tags: caching, cuda, gpgpu, prefetch, ptx

I understand that Fermi GPUs support prefetching to L1 or L2 cache. However, in the CUDA reference manual I can not find any thing about it.

Dues CUDA allow my kernel code to prefetch specific data to a specific level of cache?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well not at instruction level but detailed information about prefetching in GPUs in here:

[Many-Thread Aware Prefetching Mechanisms for GPGPU Applications](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~hyesoon/lee_micro10.pdf)
(paper in the the ACM symposium on microarchitecture 2010)

You can find instruction reference in nVIDIA's [PTX ISA reference](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html) document; the relevant instructions are [`prefetch` and `prefetchu`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#data-movement-and-conversion-instructions-prefetch-prefetchu).

Comment: I appreciate the information. It is a pity that CUDA does not provide prefetching instructions.

Comment: Updated the links... but is that paper still relevant these days (i.e. for the Maxwell and Pascal microarchitectures?)